# How to Hide Widgets From search result 'No posts matching the query' in blogger?

Tags: xml, blogger

I want to hide Some widgets from search result " no post matching the query " page. I have used the bellow code, but it's only working with " Showing posts sorted by relevance for query " page.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchQuery'>
      <style type='text/css'>
        div#HTML4{display:none !important;}
        div#HTML2{display:none !important;}
        div#FollowByEmail1{display:none !important;}
        div#HTML3{display:none !important;}
        div#HTML1{display:none !important;}
        </style>
    </b:if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default this code will work on every search page, to make it work when there is no search result, add another condition to check number of search results on the page.

> **New Condition** : *When its a search page* and *there are no posts*.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchQuery and data:numPosts == 0'>
  <style type='text/css'>
    div#HTML4{display:none !important;}
    div#HTML2{display:none !important;}
    div#FollowByEmail1{display:none !important;}
    div#HTML3{display:none !important;}
    div#HTML1{display:none !important;}
  </style>
</b:if>
```

**data:numPosts** will only work inside **main** section, you have to add this code in main section.